# Correct way to parse a String of data

Tags: java, string, oop, parsing, performance

I'm fairly new to programming and I've recently built an Android application that reads data from a USB serial device using USB OTG. I read the data into a byte buffer, convert it into a String and then parse the string so that I can select and use different parts of the data to display different things on my app. 
 I do this by first using `example.substring(example.lastIndexOf("123");` to split the string up and lose the first part of the string that I don not need, I then check the length of the substring to make sure the data is correct, next I convert the substring data into a char array so that I'm able to select different data elements of the array and display them on screen. This seems to work but I just feel like its messy and probably the incorrect way to parse the string.
Could someone please give me an Idea of whether there's a more efficient way to parse the string or if I should carry with my current method.
For example:

```
String s = "Serial Data String TX, ID: 1, UOD: 1234, OK";
String ss = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("ID: "));

int len = ss.length();
char[] c = ss.toCharArray();

if (len == 20) {

if (c[4] == '1') {

String mSubstring = ss.substring(12, 16);
tv1.setText(mSubString);
```

Is this a messy/ineficient method?

Comment: Exactly what elements of the string do you want to parse/verify? Your string seems to be delimited by commas, you can use s.split(",") to split on them.

Comment: Take into account that variable ss is as huge as the s is. Performing substring creates new String with the char array taken from the src String. So freeing memory by simply setting s to null doesn't work. Take a look on the substring method

Comment: What is the expected output?. Will the String always be the same?

Comment: The elements I would like are "1" and "1234" so that I can display these on screen as ID: 1 and OUD: 1234

Comment: @cbrook - will you always have ID, UOD etc in your string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is one way of doing it, though a bit error/exception prone. For example

```
s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("ID: "));
```

may result in `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because [lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-) may return `-1`. You have to check for that and react accordingly.

Also the use of fixed length and index might lead to errors too, better is to determine those dynamically.

I would do it another way, by splitting the original String to smaller part and then parsing them. Your example String

```
String s = "Serial Data String TX, ID: 1, UOD: 1234, OK";
```

seem to be splittable by `,`, so doing `s.split(", ")` in a first step will result in the following sub-strings

```
String[] subs = {"Serial Data String TX", "ID: 1", "UOD: 1234", "OK"};
```

in a second step you could than split by a space for example for the second element in the first array

```
subs[1].split(": ")
```

will result in

```
String[] subs2 = {"ID", "1"}
```

and so on.

Do not forget to check if elements are present before trying to access them.

**UPDATE**

Here is one possible implementation using the above approach

```
public void testSplit() {
    String s = "Serial Data String TX, ID: 1, UOD: 1234, OK";

    String[] subs = s.split("\\s*,\\s*");

    String id = "not available";
    String uod = "not available";

    if(subs.length > 1) {
        String[] subsId = subs[1].split("\\s*:\\s*");
        if("ID".equals(subsId[0]) && subsId.length > 1) {
            id = subsId[1];
        }
    }

    if(subs.length > 2) {
        String[] subsUod = subs[2].split("\\s*:\\s*");
        if("UOD".equals(subsUod[0]) && subsUod.length > 1) {
            uod = subsUod[1];
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("ID=%s%nUOD=%s%n", id, uod);
}
```

Output is

```
ID=1
UOD=1234
```

If you don't exactly know where `ID` and `UOD` are placed in the original string then you might want to loop over the the result of the first split and do the second split on each, then check if element at index `0` is one of those you are looking for, if yes then check if you have an element at index `1`, if yes take that value, other wise no value is available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like the idea of this method, it seems like it would be a lot cleaner!

Comment: @cbrook cool, I've added a code example you might want to check.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting the string to a char array, you could use substring and compare directly:

```
if (len == 20 && "1".equals(ss.substring(4, 1)) {
    String mSubstring = ss.substring(12, 16);
    tv1.setText(mSubString);
}
```

Or you start the substring after `ID:` and use `startsWith()`:

```
String s = "Serial Data String TX, ID: 1, UOD: 1234, OK";
String ss = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("ID: ") + "ID: ".length());

int len = ss.length();

if (len == 16 && ss.startsWith("1")) {
    String mSubstring = ss.substring(8, 12);
    tv1.setText(mSubString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are various ways you can design this, here I am going to tell you which looks best and at the same time not too complex approach

First create a class which will hold the Serial Data properties like ID, UOD etc.

Then as you already have delimiter like "," and inner delimiter like ":", use them to split and use trim to get the actual result, try to make it generalized so than future new properties can be accommodate with minimum changes. Please let me know if you looking for code level explanation for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```java
String s = "Serial Data String TX, ID: 1, UOD: 1234, OK";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ID: (\\d+), UOD: (\\d+), (\\w+)");

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("ID: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("UOD: " + m.group(2));
    System.out.println("Status: " + m.group(3));
}
```

This will show:

```
ID: 1
UOD: 1234
Status: OK
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know string pattern it is better to use regular expression. For example if you want to know **UOD** value then

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*UOD:\\s?(\\d+),\\s?OK)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return matcher.group(2);
        }
        return null;
```

Comment: Tha's a nice way too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex like this :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "Serial Data String TX, ID: 1, UOD: 1234, OK";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(?::\\s+)(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + " - " + m.group(2));
 // add group1 as key and group2 as value to a map if you want the values to persist.
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
ID - 1
UOD - 1234
```